# Cannot Connect VNC through SSH to Windows from Unix

Tags: windows-10, ssh, unix, vnc, ssh-tunnel

I mostly have Unix devices and use VNC through SSH to connect to all of them.  However I have one Windows 10 PC and I cannot remote into it.

On the Windows 10 PC, I installed TightVNC Server (Version 2.8.63), listening on port 5900.  **I can successfully VNC to it without SSH.**

I also set up OpenSSH on the Windows PC.  It listens on port 22002.  **I can SSH successfully SSH into the PC.**

Next I build the tunnel from my Unix device, with `ssh -L 5901:localhost:5900 username@10.0.0.111 -p 22002`. **The tunnel successfully builds.**  I next try to establish the VNC session from my Unix device, connecting to `localhost:5901`.   This is where it fails, I get the response:

> Connection failed to "localhost".  Unable to communicate with
> "localhost".  Make sure the remote computer is available and the
> firewall is not blocking screen sharing.

[Connection Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/81vA8.png)

Things I've tried:

- Disabling all firewalls on the Windows PC, to be sure
- Enabling 'Allow Loopback Connections' in TightVNC preferences
- In the sshd_config file, I set 'GatewayPorts yes', 'PermitTunnel
  yes', and 'AllowStreamLocalForwarding yes'

Any other ideas??

Comment: Have you try with hostname or IP instead of `localhost`?

Comment: I haven’t and can try later, however I use localhost:5901 when tunneling into other Unix hosts.  So I suspect the config issue is on the server (Windows) side.

Comment: Oh you might be saying to change localhost in the SSH command… I will definitely try that and report back.

Comment: That was it!  Instead of building the SSH tunnel with 
`ssh -L 5901:localhost:5900 username@10.0.0.111 -p 22002` 

I need to build the SSH tunnel with 
`ssh -L 5901:127.0.0.1:6900 username@10.0.0.111 -p 22002`.

Not sure why Windows doesn't like localhost there, but it's working now.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Romeo Ninov for pointing this out.  When building the SSH tunnel to windows, the loopback address needs to be used, not localhost.  So instead of:

```
ssh -L 5901:localhost:5900 username@10.0.0.111 -p 22002
```

I needed to use:

```
ssh -L 5901:127.0.0.1:5900 username@10.0.0.111 -p 22002
```